# Magento 2 : cart rule (coupon) not working for some customers

Tags: magento2

I have created a cart rule (type - coupon), but it's not working for some of the customers even though those customers seem eligible for the coupon discounts.

Rule

[image]
I am trying to understand & want to know
is any table exist which stores the customer & cart rule relationship

So, I can check into that table & get an idea of why coupons not working for these customers.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: are there any conditions?